# Getting div to run to the right side of the screen

Tags: css, xhtml

Basically i'm trying to get a divider to run to the right edge of the screen (without overflow).

If you look here: http://gomysites.com and scroll down to the twitter section you will see i've set the twitter panel to run off to the left edge of the screen (no matter the size).

Now i want to do exactly the same on the right side. If you notice the grey divider between the blog posts id like this to run to the right edge of the screen (no matter the size) without it adding a horizontal scroller.

I've tried setting the css for the divider exactly opposite as i did for the titter panel:

```
.widget_gomy_news .divider{
margin:30px -10000px 30px 0;
background:#f3f3f3;
height:30px;
float:right;
width:610px;
padding:0 10000px 0 0;
}
```

But it adds a horizontal scroller. So i did try adding overflow:hidden; to the body. Which removes the scroller but i can still scroll everything left and right with the mouse.

Anyone got any ideas how i can achieve what i'm after? or will i need to use some js to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide us an example of what you already got? Then we might be able to see the issues and try to solve it on a live page using Firebug.

Comment: I've added a link above to the page in question. I'll set the divider as i want it now... you'll notice it adds a horizontal scroller onto the page (which i dont want).

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the -10000px right margin and the 10000px right padding and it works. What do you need that for?

Comment: If i remove the margin + padding it will look like this: http://gomysites.com/1.jpg (which aint right) what i want it to look like is: http://gomysites.com/2.jpg with the divider running to the edge of the screen on the right (without overflow). Like the twitter panel does on the left.

Comment: If I add an "overflow-x: hidden" to the body, I don't have a horizontal scrollbar (in FF and Chrome).

Comment: Oh sorry about that Kau, didn't see your comment before I posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow-x: hidden` on the body element. This will prevent the horizontal scroll but may trip you up in older versions of IE - Tested in IE8 and Chrome.

**Edit:**

You could also write some jQuery to grab the Window viewport height/width like: `$(window).height();`, and size your entire page's "container" div accordingly. This will allow you to know what numbers you're working with for setting the negative/position margins in your "divider" hack.

Comment: Yes i've tried that already and yes it does remove the horizontal scroll, but i can still scroll left and right with my mouse.

Comment: Hmm this is strange. Side scrolling with the mouse doesn't happen in Chrome, but it will in IE/FF.

Comment: But what is the issue if a user (that has a 4D Scroll Wheel and does accidently scroll to the side) can scroll horizontally with his mouse?

Answer (score 0):

I think i've sorted it. I wrapped all the page content inside a div and added overflow hidden to that (rather than body). This worked in everything except IE7, but i can do a simple work around for IE7. Thanks for all the replies, Jeff sent me down the right path thanks.